# How to undo automatic character replacement in gnome-terminal?

Tags: shell, autocomplete, gnome-terminal, debian-stretch

I've created an annoying feature that I can't undo. While installing some different terminal themes, I installed a script that replaces some of my terminal characters with symbols when I'm typing, such as replacing > (right carrot) with ⇒ (double right arrow). I have tried resetting the shell, purging and reinstalling gnome-terminal, deleting .bashrc, etc., and I can't get this behavior to stop. I didn't realize this behavior until a few days after playing around with themes, so I can't recreate my steps to figure out what I installed that caused it.

Any suggestions?

(I'm running Debian 9.8 Stretch, gnome-terminal 3.22.2)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SuperUser! Can you try changing the terminal font to a default one? Looks like you installed a font wit _ligatures_, like [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode).

Comment: That's it! What an obvious issue in retrospect. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, you installed a font with [ligatures](https://www.lifewire.com/ligature-in-typography-1078102) (like [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) for example), which replace multiple chars with different (possibly "combined") chars to "beautify" the script.

If you don't like the effect, it's then a matter of changing your terminal font to the default one, or any other one *without* ligatures.

Comment: It's interesting how OP can face this behavior and how your response could fix it for them... because gnome-terminal doesn't support ligatures.